# Generating representatives for cosets

Tags: group-theory, elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

Let $p$ be a prime number and let $n\geq 1$ be coprime to $p$. Consider the groups
$$G:=(\mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z)^\times\ni p,\quad H:=\langle p\rangle\leq G.$$

We may now form the quotient $G/H$, giving us say $k$ cosets. It is often desirable to have a system of representatives $g_1,\dots,g_k$ of the cosets, and it would sometimes be even more useful to have all the $g_i$ be a power of the same $g$. Hence the question: Do we *always* manage to find some $g\in G$ for which $1,g,\dots, g^{k-1}$ forms a system of representatives?

In case $p$ generates $G$, there is of course nothing to prove, just take $g=1$. However, what if $p$ does not generate $G$? For instance, consider  $m=11$ and $p=3$. Then $\langle p\rangle=\{1,3,4,5,9\}$, and the choice $g=1$ does not work. In this case, we have two cosets to consider, and the elements $2$ and $2^2$ lie in two different cosets, so that we can take $g=2$.

Is this always possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No this is not always possible, mainly because unit groups of integer rings are not in general cyclic and can have arbitrarily many generators.

For example, if we take $n=24$, then the unit group $U(24)$ is elementary abelian of order $8$ and all of its nontrivial elements have order $2$. Then we could take $p=5$ for example, and we are looking for four coset representatives, and it clear that they cannot have form $\{1,g,g^2,g^3\}$ because $g^2=1$ for all $g$.